# How to output a variable's value in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm new to JQuery and I'm making a text based/command line game etc for a 1st year uni project.

I'm trying to create an inventory feature and i have a variable which contains the one item the player can hold. Then if the user types 'inhand' I want the output to be 'you are holding 'inhand'. Here is part of my code so far but I can't get the variable to output it's just blank.

```
var inhand = "nothing";

//torch
        else if (input == "pickup torch") {
                $('<p>You picked up the torch.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
                inhand = "torch";
        }

        //inhand
        else if (input == "inhand") {
                $('<p>You are currently holding a </p>' + inhand ).insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        }
```

as you can see in the penultimate line i have 'you are holding' + inhand. This doesn't work however it just leaves a blank space. 
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa|Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!--Google fonts-->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!--Google fonts-->
  <link rel=stylesheet href="scripts/AlbaCSS.css" type="text/css" />
   <title>Alba</title>
   </head>
   <body>

<div id="container">
<div id="console">
<p id="message_begin">Welcome to Alba. At any time you may type "help". Also try using 'pickup [itemname]' to collect items.</p>

<p id="area_main">Alba finds herself at the opening of a forest. Visability is low but she can see paths: 'north', 'east', 'west' and also a 'gate'. On the floor there is a key slightly hidden under a pile of leaves.</p>

<p id="message_help" style="display:none;">Help: <br />
<i>A</i><br />
<i>list</i><br />
<i>of</i><br />
<i>commands</i><br />
<i>would</i><br />
<i>appear</i> </p>

</div>

<!-- ALLOWS CONTENT TO BE INSERTED BEFORE THIS -->
<div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>

<!-- INPUT -->
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<center><input type="text" id="command_line" size="50" autofocus="autofocus" /></center>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/game.js"></script>


</body> 
</html>




    // JavaScript Document

// Variables for the game
var inhand = "nothing"; //For picking up items
var lifepoints = 1; //How many lives Alba has

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message_begin").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#area_main").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#command_line").fadeIn(3000);
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var input = $("#command_line").val();

        //help
        if (input.indexOf("help") > -1) {
            if (input == "help") {
                $("#message_help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        }
        //end help


        //pickup
        else if (input == "pickup") {
                $('<p>pickup what? Be specific. Type "help" for a list of all commands.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            }

            //key
            else if (input == "pickup key") {
                    $('<p>You picked up the key.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
                    inhand = "key";
            }

            //torch
            else if (input == "pickup torch") {
                    $('<p>You picked up the torch.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
                    inhand = "torch";
            }

            //inhand
            else if (input == "inhand") {
                    $('<p>You are currently holding a </p>' + inhand ).insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
            }


        else if (input != "") {
            $('<p>I don\'t understand "' + input + '"</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        }

        $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);
        $("#command_line").val("");
});
});
```

Comment: Please also post the HTML, especially the part containing `#placeholder`.

Comment: I've added the complete files now for both JS and the HTML, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that

```
'<p>You are currently holding a </p>' + inhand
```

Should be

```
'<p>You are currently holding a '+inhand+'</p>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, fixed it! Just realised how stupid I was I did the correct thing on a few lines below anyway -.-